# DataGridView not losing focus

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem with the datagridview in c# forms. I have a combo box column in dgv1, when i select a value, the value isn't really selected until i press a button or a text field or anything else. The odd thing that when i press on the tool strip menu, the box in the dgv1 is not losing focus, so for example i select a value in the combo box , and then i press File->Save i get an error.

I read other questions similar to mine and I saw that the problem might be with validation.
I tried to add  `this.Validate();` in the cell end edit function for the dgv, but that didn't work. 
I also tried to add that in the tool strip menu click event, validating the dgv, refreshing it and many other function, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please provide small sample code that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I added datagridview.endedit() in the save button in the toolstrip. Works fine now.